# Apache Virtual Hosts not working for my two domains

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost, multisite

Ubuntu Server 20.04 on VirtualBox. I can access only the content of website1 from my web browser on a windows host, whenever I visit website 2 it redirects me to website1 but shows website2 as the domain name. I have edited my windows hosts file to map website1 and website2 to the local IP of the VM:

I installed Apache2, created the directories and gave permissions:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/website1/public_html
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/website2/public_html

sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/website1/public_html
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/website2/public_html

sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Index.html with different content for each website:

```
/var/www/website1/public_html/index.html
/var/www/website2/public_html/index.html
```

I've created the two conf files for each domain with the following configuration:

**Website1:**

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/website1.conf: 

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
    ServerAdmin admin@website1.com
    ServerName www.website1.com
    ServerAlias www.website1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website1.com/public_html
    ...
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

**Website2:**

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/website2.conf:  

<VirtualHost *:80>
      ...
        ServerAdmin admin@website2.com
        ServerName www.website2.com
        ServerAlias www.website2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/website2.com/public_html
        ...
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ...
    </VirtualHost>
```

I enabled and disabled default apache site:

```
sudo a2ensite website1.conf
sudo a2ensite website2.conf
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

I followed this guide on digital ocean, as well as multiple others with no luck.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-20-04

I also tried adding a Directory block within the conf to both website1.conf and website2.conf:

**Website1:**

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/website1.conf: 

<Directory /var/www/website1.com/public_html>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

**Website2:**

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/website2.conf: 
            
<Directory /var/www/website2.com/public_html>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

Pretty stumped, following multiple guides and official Apache documentation this should work right but surely I am missing something. Guessing it's resolution related.

The only thing that seems to work is port based virtual hosts, so I configured website1 as default port 80 and website2 as 8081 etc. Unpractical though because I had to manual type port 8081 if I wanted website2.